# Optimize custom database queries

Tags: 8, database

I am building my first Drupal 8 module and wondering how to optimize work with multiple queries to the database?

```
$query = \Drupal::database();
$transaction = $query->startTransaction();
$product = new ProductController();

try {
  if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    $product->product_update($fields, $_GET['pid']);
  } else {
    $product->product_insert($fields);
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $transaction->rollback();
  throw $e;
}
```

As you can see I am starting a transaction in order to reverse update of databese in case something went wrong and for this, I need to establish a connection `$query = \Drupal::database();` but inside the try catch I am calling functions that again are calling `\Drupal::database()` :

```
public function product_update($fields, $id) {
$query = \Drupal::database();
$query->update('product')
  ->fields($fields)
  ->condition('pid', $id)
  ->execute();}
```

So my question is what is the correct way of working in such an approach?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) What makes you think there’s anything wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Thank you, isn't every "$query = \Drupal::database()" establish new connection to database and "$query->startTransaction();" wont work because other $query was started in the function(_update, _insert)?

Comment: Sanitize/check that GET

Comment: @serj adding more queries is fine.